# delete bundle file in iOS app

Tags: ios, bundle

Here is the problem:
I am trying to check the contents of my app's bundle. So by writing a couple of lines of code like:

```
NSBundle *myBundle = [NSBundle mainBundle];
NSLog(@"%@",myBundle);
```

I got the path that I need to locate my app's bundle. However, when I deleted the bundle, I was expecting my app to give an error saying that bundle doesn't exist. Instead, it showed that same path again. Hy doesn't it have any impact on the program. How does it work under the hoods? I am new to iOS, so any help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Hi. Can you post code how you delete the main bundle?

Comment: I just followed the path that  was getting printed in the above code and then deleted the folder.I guess i'm really messing up something here.

Comment: What purpose do you want to achieve? Just deleting the main bundle or what?

Comment: Is the path that I got when I tried to print the 'myBundle' object the mainBundle of my App?If yes then on deleting that folder ,why doesn't my program stop working?

Comment: I dunno :). Perhaps before a Simulator starts It loads in the memory all apps present in work folder. Check this - delete the app from a running simulator (not from a disk) and check will be this app deleted from disk.